# The annotation @PersistenceContext is disallowed for this location

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistência

Estou recebendo a mensagem    "The annotation @PersistenceContext is disallowed for this location" quando tento colocar essa anotação no código, alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

```
@Stateless
public class ReajusteManager  {

public List<PlanoSaudeDTO> listarPlanoSaude() {


    @PersistenceContext //Local do erro
    EntityManager entityManager;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object[]> listaValores = (List<Object[]>) entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT F.NM_FUNCIONARIO\r\n" + 
    "FROM DBO_DB_RH.VW_funcionario F \r\n" + 
    "Where  rownum <30 \r\n" + 
    "Order by F.NM_FUNCIONARIO").getResultList();

    List<PlanoSaudeDTO> listaPlanoSaudeDTO = new ArrayList<PlanoSaudeDTO>();
    System.out.println("aqui");

    for (Object[] obj : listaValores) {
        PlanoSaudeDTO plano = new PlanoSaudeDTO();

        plano.setNomeFuncionario(String.valueOf(obj[0]));

        listaPlanoSaudeDTO.add(plano);
    }

    return listaPlanoSaudeDTO;

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa anotação não serve para variáveis locais dentro dos métodos. Serve apenas para variáveis de instância, que estão fora dos métodos e dentro da classe.

Faça assim:

```
@Stateless
public class ReajusteManager  {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private static final String LISTA_FUNCIONARIOS_SQL = 
            "SELECT F.NM_FUNCIONARIO \r\n" + 
            "FROM DBO_DB_RH.VW_funcionario F \r\n" + 
            "WHERE rownum <30 \r\n" + 
            "ORDER BY F.NM_FUNCIONARIO"

    public List<PlanoSaudeDTO> listarPlanoSaude() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Object[]> listaValores = (List<Object[]>)
                entityManager.createNativeQuery(LISTA_FUNCIONARIOS_SQL).getResultList();

        List<PlanoSaudeDTO> listaPlanoSaudeDTO = new ArrayList<PlanoSaudeDTO>();
        System.out.println("aqui");

        for (Object[] obj : listaValores) {
            PlanoSaudeDTO plano = new PlanoSaudeDTO();
            plano.setNomeFuncionario(String.valueOf(obj[0]));
            listaPlanoSaudeDTO.add(plano);
        }

        return listaPlanoSaudeDTO;
    }
}
```

Não garanto que não haja outros erros. Mas pelo menos o problema que você relata deve ser corrigido.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Obrigado!

Comment: @B.Fernandes Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como aceita ao clicar no ✔️ que está no lado esquerdo da resposta.